# BigUnsigned integer (C++)

Tags: c++, biginteger

I have used [this library](http://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).
I have to perform bit operations on BigUnsigned numbers.

My code is

```
#include "BigIntegerLibrary.h"
BigUnsigned n1;

for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
{
    if (i < 5)
    {
        n1.setBit(i,true);
    }
    else
    {
        n1.setBit(i,false);
    }
}

BigUnsigned n2;
n2 = n1;
n2.bitShiftLeft(n2 , 40);
```

It gives me `n2` is `0` instead of `34084860461056`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It works well for me. What OS and compiler/IDE are you using? Also, if you are outputting the `n2` value, please show how are you doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the implementation of the library. I would highly recommend using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) for this task. My solution would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    mpz_class n2 = 0x1F;

    n2 <<= 40;

    cout << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have used "[mattmccutchen.net/bigint/]" library for bigInteger.

Comment: yes, so you can use a different library to do what you're trying to do. GMP is MUCH more powerful that that bigInteger library.

Comment: If i used GMP library  function "void mpz_init2 (mpz t x, mp bitcnt t n)". Can it give me exact 125 bit number?                                    Can i use this GMP library in indesign SDK?

Comment: You can use it in conjunction with any SDK. It's just a library after all. And I haven't tested it, but it's pretty good at giving exact numbers. I've calculated one million factorial to every significant figure using GMP on my macbook. So I would go off on a limb and say that it could give you an exact 125 bit number.